# How to merge 2 column into 1 column TO output in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.doctor_name, a.patient_name, s.date, s.time FROM appointments AS a LEFT JOIN doctors AS d ON d.id = a.doctor_id LEFT JOIN slots AS s ON  s.id = a.slot_id WHERE s.date > '2019-10-01' ORDER BY d.doctor_name DESC ";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo '<pre>';
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    print_r($row);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

and it's output is:

```
Array
(
    [doctor_name] => Khaled
    [patient_name] => Nawaz
    [date] => 2019-10-11
    [time] => 02:01
)
Array
(
    [doctor_name] => Khaled
    [patient_name] => Anik
    [date] => 2019-10-07
    [time] => 02:31
)
Array
(
    [doctor_name] => Khaled
    [patient_name] => Manik
    [date] => 2019-10-02
    [time] => 03:31
)
```

Can I merge the `date` and `time` column as **slot_date_time**?

So output will be e.g:

```
Array
(
    [doctor_name] => Khaled
    [patient_name] => Manik
    [slot_date_time] => 2019-10-02 03:31
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT d.doctor_name, a.patient_name, CONCAT(s.date, ',', s.time) AS slot_date_time  
FROM appointments AS a LEFT JOIN doctors AS d 
ON d.id = a.doctor_id LEFT JOIN slots AS s 
ON  s.id = a.slot_id 
WHERE s.date > '2019-10-01' 
ORDER BY d.doctor_name DESC
```

Use `CONCAT` for merge two column as one column

Comment: can you help me one more thing?

Comment: I have this Q2 and Q3 here: https://hackmd.io/@IxUhK9OGTOyHlMrvmthXdA/BJIGlfA0B

Comment: first you try if any issue than share here

Comment: can you tell me the sql clauses which I need to see?

Comment: See here: [Link](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/hospital-database-exercise/sql-exercise-on-hospital-database.php)

Comment: for Q2: `SELECT d.doctor_name, count(DISTINCT a.doctor_id) AS 'appointment_count' FROM appointments AS a LEFT JOIN doctors AS d ON d.id = a.doctor_id` is it right? I see doctor_id = 22 and 23 has same no of appointments. So my output is showing for the 23

Comment: you want to get both record or single?

Comment: as the questions asked "highest number of appointments: so I need the single one.

Comment: so you got your solution from this query